# $y' = g(x,y)$ equation intrepetation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

If we consider a differential equation $y' = g(x,y)$, what would $g(x,y)$ represent here? What is a practical interpretation of this function? My textbook says that $g$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$. But this does not seem to me to be much of an explanation...
It may be useful to note that this is taken from the derivation of Euler's method for solving differential equations. Here $y = f(x)$ is an unknown function

Comment: The slope at a point is a function of the coordinates... what more are you looking for?

Comment: @SeanRoberson; So for example, given values of both $x$ and $y$, we have a $y' = n$, where $n$ is some value obtained by $g(x,y) = n$?. What does the 'function of the coordinates' mean, it is not the conventional $g(x) = y$?

Comment: Consider $y' = x - y.$ What is the slope at $(3, 1)?$ Plug in.

Comment: @SeanRoberson; Does $g$ here represent as you said function of the coordinates, for example, if we have $y' = -2xy$, $g$ is here $-2xy$, that is, a function of both x and y. This then becomes just an ordinary differential equation...

Comment: @SeanRoberson; The slope is $3-1 = 2$, but here $g$ would be $x-y$,  ($g = x-y$), correct?

Comment: In short, yes. $g$ is a function of two variables (yes, they exist).

Comment: In algebra classes, when discussing graphs of equations in the abstract you may have seen a phrase similar to "let $y = f(x)$". Or, what you would say here is "let the graph $y$ be given by the function $f(x)$". You can think of the statement $y = f(x)$ as an analogy for your statement $y' = g(x,y)$. When you want to discuss differential equations in the abstract, you might use the statement $y' = g(x,y)$ as a way to symbolize what a differential equation is.

Comment: Thank you @MattE.; That was a helpful hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $v=g(x,y)$, the function $g$ is just a function of 2 variables.

In $y'=g(x,y)$ the function value stands for a slope, one may think of the line $y=y_0+g(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)$ at the point $(x_0,y_0)$. Of solutions to the differential equation it is demanded that they be tangent to this line in the point $(x_0,y_0)$ for every point of the solution curve.

In the Euler method and interpretations of other methods (like collocation methods), this tangency condition is reduced to the nodes of a discretization of the $x$ interval. The segments between the nodes are filled with (piecewise) linear or polynomial functions. In some reduced sense this also works for the more popular methods like RK4, see [Visualization of Third Order Runge-Kutta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361563/visualization-of-third-order-runge-kutta/3362041#3362041).